# What are the advantages of leaving out out the protocol for src=?

Tags: html, url, protocol-relative

I see that the `src` URL for jQuery has no protocol specified:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

Is this standard?
What are the pros and cons of leaving out the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand. It'll use whatever protocol the current source is using without having to state it explicitly and avoiding possible mixed content warnings.

See the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), sections 3 and 4.2